# Why C# generic program performs better than a program hand specialized variant for a specific type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I was reading the [Design and Implementation of Generics for the
.NET Common Language Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2001/01/designandimplementationofgenerics.pdf). In performance section, it says the generic code is as or more efficient than the hand specialized version.

I created a benchmarking for this and verified it for a simple stack using .NET benchmarking library.

*Results for both string and double type*

**Type - Double**

```
                                  Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
---------------------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
     GenericStackPushAndPopForTypeDouble | 5.038 ns | 0.0522 ns | 0.0489 ns |
      ObjectStackPushAndPopForTypeDouble | 7.619 ns | 0.0842 ns | 0.0787 ns |
 HandWrittenStackPushAndPopForTypeDouble | 5.722 ns | 0.0594 ns | 0.0555 ns |
```

**Type - String**

```
                                  Method |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |
---------------------------------------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|
     GenericStackPushAndPopForTypeString | 3.817 ns | 0.0103 ns | 0.0080 ns |
      ObjectStackPushAndPopForTypeString | 4.764 ns | 0.0345 ns | 0.0322 ns |
 HandWrittenStackPushAndPopForTypeString | 4.099 ns | 0.0298 ns | 0.0249 ns |
```

I am really surprised that generic code is outperforming my handwritten code. I tried looking into the IL code generated for both case, but I could not figure out anything interesting. The only main diff is generics is using `ldelem !0/*T*/`where as specialized (for double) code is using `ldelm.r8`.

Am I missing some optimization happening at runtime?

### Edit

Even I have tried using WinDbg to get the jitted assembly code for both and could not figure out any difference there.

### Code

```
// Generic stack 
public class GenericStack<T>
    {
        private int _size;
        private T[] _stack;

        public GenericStack()
        {
            _size = 0;
            _stack = new T[10]; 
        }

        public void Push(T value)
        {
            if (_size >= _stack.Length)
            {
                var newStack = new  T [2*_size];
                Array.Copy(_stack, newStack, _size);
                _stack = newStack;
            }
            _stack[_size++] = value;
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            return _stack[--_size];
        }
    }

// Stack using object
public class ObjectStack
{
    private int _size;
    private object[] _stack;

    public ObjectStack()
    {
        _size = 0;
        _stack = new object[10]; 
    }

    public void Push(object value)
    {
        if (_size >= _stack.Length)
        {
            var newStack = new  object[2*_size];
            Array.Copy(_stack, newStack, _size);
            _stack = newStack;
        }
        _stack[_size++] = value;
    }

    public object Pop()
    {
        return _stack[--_size];
    }
}

// Hand specialized for double type stack
public class HandWrittenDoubleStack
    {
        private int _size;
        private double[] _stack;

        public HandWrittenDoubleStack()
        {
            _size = 0;
            _stack = new double[10];
        }

        public void Push(double value)
        {
            if (_size >= _stack.Length)
            {
                var newStack = new double[2 * _size];
                Array.Copy(_stack, newStack, _size);
                _stack = newStack;
            }
            _stack[_size++] = value;
        }

        public double Pop()
        {
            return _stack[--_size];
        }
    }

// Hand specialized for string type stack
public class HandWrittenStringStack
{
    private int _size;
    private string[] _stack;

    public HandWrittenStringStack()
    {
        _size = 0;
        _stack = new string[10];
    }

    public void Push(string value)
    {
        if (_size >= _stack.Length)
        {
            var newStack = new string[2 * _size];
            Array.Copy(_stack, newStack, _size);
            _stack = newStack;
        }
        _stack[_size++] = value;
    }

    public string Pop()
    {
        return _stack[--_size];
    }
}

// Benchmarking code
[ClrJob]
public class BenchMarkGenericsWithDouble
{
    private readonly double data;
    private GenericStack<double> _genericStack;
    private ObjectStack _objectStack;
    private HandWrittenDoubleStack _handWrittenDoubleStack;

    public BenchMarkGenericsWithDouble()
    {
        _genericStack = new GenericStack<double>();
        _objectStack = new ObjectStack();
        _handWrittenDoubleStack = new HandWrittenDoubleStack();
        data = new Random(13).NextDouble();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double GenericStackPushAndPopForTypeDouble()
    {
        _genericStack.Push(data);
        return _genericStack.Pop();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public object ObjectStackPushAndPopForTypeDouble()
    {
        _objectStack.Push(data);
        return _objectStack.Pop();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public double HandWrittenStackPushAndPopForTypeDouble()
    {
        _handWrittenDoubleStack.Push(data);
        return _handWrittenDoubleStack.Pop();
    }
}

[ClrJob]
public class BenchMarkGenericsWithString
{
    private readonly string stringData;
    private GenericStack<string> _genericStack;
    private ObjectStack _objectStack;
    private HandWrittenStringStack _handWrittenStringStack;

    public BenchMarkGenericsWithString()
    {
        _genericStack = new GenericStack<string>();
        _objectStack = new ObjectStack();
        _handWrittenStringStack = new HandWrittenStringStack();
        stringData = "asdfasf";
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string GenericStackPushAndPopForTypeString()
    {
        _genericStack.Push(stringData);
        return _genericStack.Pop();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public object ObjectStackPushAndPopForTypeString()
    {
        _objectStack.Push(stringData);
        return _objectStack.Pop();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string HandWrittenStackPushAndPopForTypeString()
    {
        _handWrittenStringStack.Push(stringData);
        return _handWrittenStringStack.Pop();
    }
}

// Main method
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var summaryDouble = BenchmarkRunner.Run<BenchMarkGenericsWithDouble>();
    var summaryString = BenchmarkRunner.Run<BenchMarkGenericsWithString>();
}
```

Comment: Code for both cases, maybe?

Comment: Sorry!
Code : https://gist.github.com/vrnithinkumar/b44537c5f59dbe670a1694bb3c0cecd1

Comment: Did you disable optimizations on the GenericStack case? You have no clue what type of optimizations the runtime environment does otherwise - and it probably won't optimize your IL code.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar - Please don't link to external sites like that. You should always include the code in the actual question.

Comment: Maybe the fact that Generic<T> had to be instantly JITted and optimized before first use with <double>, while JITing and/or optimization for Handwritten could trigger a bit later?

Comment: BTW. how did you measure the time? Did you leave some "warmup" time? i.e. say you ran 1e6 elements, but have you actually ignored the time for the first 1e4..1e5 elements to stabilize the runtime and caching?

Comment: @Enigmativity  I did not know. Sorry.

Comment: Please include the benchmark code as well, so the whole thing can be independently reproduced. Presumably you're using benchmark.net and I can guess what it looks like, but not guessing is better.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Updated with benchmarking code.

Comment: You're still missing `ObjectStack` and `HandWrittenStringStack`, but I'll let that slide since they're easy to produce. Voted to reopen. FWIW I see the same discrepancy on my machine.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Apologies. Updated with both object stack and HandWrittenStringStack code

Comment: In my opinion the IL doesn't matter much, especially with generic code. Try viewing the generated assembly instead.

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis I have tried using WinDbg to get the jitted assembly code for both and could not figure out any difference there.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar Could you include the assembly listings of the methods of both classes?

Comment: Note that you don't need WinDbg, benchmark.net has disassembly [built in](http://adamsitnik.com/Disassembly-Diagnoser). Annoyingly, though, it gives no output on my machine for the generic version for the legacy JIT. For RyuJIT, the assembly output is nearly identical save for some moved code blocks and the inlining of `Pop`, and the time difference is lost in the error bound.